# How do I end line when writing to a text file?

Tags: java, text-files, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I'm writing to a text file but when I look into the file everything is in on line even though I'm adding "\n" in the string in the for-loop. What am I overlooking?

```
File file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "\\SavedJavaArithmetic.txt");

FileWriter fileW = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter buffW = new BufferedWriter(fileW);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    buffW.write(list.get(i).toString() + "\n");
}
buffW.close();
fileW.close();
```

The arraylist "list" is already created and filled when the for loop starts.

Comment: Why are you iterating over an empty list? That is definitely not what you want

Comment: I had just added that line to show that there was an arraylist even though in my full code it is near the beginning and already filled.

Comment: Try `buffw.newLine()`  instead of appending `"\n"`.

Comment: Or try: `buffW.write(list.get(i).toString() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please program to the `List` interface. To your question use [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--), because `"\n"` is not cross-platform (on Windows, the line separator is `"\r\n"`). Next, `File` provides two argument constructors. And there is [`BufferedWriter.newLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine--) which might look like

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
File file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), "SavedJavaArithmetic.txt");

try (FileWriter fileW = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter buffW = new BufferedWriter(fileW)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        buffW.write(list.get(i));
        buffW.newLine();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use a `PrintWriter` (it provides a more natural syntax). And, I would use a `for-each` loop. **Also**, in both cases, I would use a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to handle the `close`(s). Putting that all together might look something like,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
File file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), "SavedJavaArithmetic.txt");
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file)) {
    for (String str : list) {
        pw.println(str);
    }
}
```

**And**, in Java 8+, using a `Stream` with a `forEachOrdered` like

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
File file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), "SavedJavaArithmetic.txt");
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file)) {
    list.stream().forEachOrdered(pw::println);
}
```